# Youtube v3 API video language

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When uploading videos on youtube, there is a Video language field that can be set. Is there a way to use the v3 api to query this field for a specific video?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not specifically by video language. You have three choices that are sort of close:

You can search by location -- this will limit results to videos within a certain radius of the coordinates you specify (there's also a locationRadius parameter to customize what that radius is).

You can search by region code, which limits results to videos uploaded from a particular country.

You can search by relevanceLanguage -- here, you put in a language, and it will rank results based on relevance to that language. In some cases this is works well for language-based searching, but in other cases you may get videos, not in the language you set here, that are just so highly relevant they are returned anyway (for example, if you set relevanceLanguge to KO for Korean, and then included the search query of 'Taylor Swift,' you'll get a mixture of Korean videos that are relevant to that term as well as things like Vevo music videos).

**UPDATE**

2 years after I posted this answer, the YouTube Data API v3 was revised to clarify that searching by `regionCode` no longer limits results to videos uploaded from a country/region, but instead videos viewable within a country/region.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So it sounds like you cannot really test video membership to various conditions, like for e.g, whether video A falls within a specific geographic location or country or relevance to a language say English? All you can do is ask for a list of videos from youtube that have conditions like relevance to English.

Comment: The first two ... geographic location and country ... should function as explicit filters (ignoring any results that don't fall within them). It's only the relevanceLanguage parameter where it tests relevance to a language rather than videos with a particular language tag set. Not sure why this is ... perhaps most people don't set the video language, and hence it wouldn't be that useful of a search filter?

Comment: @jlmcdonald do you know where can i find the relecanceLanguage codes KO is for korean where can i find the other languages codes  ?

Comment: @jlmcdonald - region code does not filter by upload country but "instructs the API to return search results for videos that can be viewed in the specified country" (from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Comment: @rainman - the language codes are 2-character ISO 639-1 language codes. You can find them here: http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

Comment: @James Yes, your comment is true as of 2017, when that change was made. I have edited the answer accordingly to reflect the updates.